# Typescript error: Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: typescript

I've got the following function

`this._list.addToFavs((<HTMLElement>event.currentTarget).dataset.code)`

where addToFavs is defined as `addtoFavs(currencyCode: string)`

I'm getting the error "Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'" as dataset.code could in theory be 'undefined'.  I know I can work around it by adding ! at the end, but I feel like it's kind of messy.  I tried adding

```
if ((<HTMLElement>event.currentTarget).dataset.code == undefined) {
  throw Error('Code not set to details fav button')
}
```

but it doesn't stop the error.  Is there any way around it besides defining currencyCode as string|undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before invoking the function, you can check the existence of specific `data` attribute.

```
const code = event.currentTarget?.dataset?.code;
if (code) {
    this._list.addToFavs(code);
}
```